# Fail to re-import .sql file generated by batch script

Tags: mysql, batch-file, windows-scripting, mysql-backup

I am using the following [Batch script](http://www.jonnyreeves.co.uk/2011/mysql-dump-backup-batch-script-for-windows/).

It generates a **.sql** file with same size as the one i get when i **manually** use the mysqldump command from the command line.

However, when i try to load this .sql to a database using :

```
mysql -u root -p db < file.sql
```

It does not load anything, no db tables/files are created. Is there an error in the script? or am i missing something?

Comment: That script creates a zip file compressed with 7-zip, how could you load it?

Comment: i use 7-zip to unzip archive, then this is how i get the .sql file.

Comment: i will change the feature of this script to create directly .sql file instead of zip, but for now i am unzipping manually.

Comment: You should try to load the SQL in some kind of management tool and try to execute from there. Usually these tools gives a nice hint of what is wrong. Sorry, but I am not a mysql expert (Still using the old MySql Query Browser).

Comment: @Steve i fixed it, if you want check my answer provided below.

Comment: @Steve  i am using mysql query browser too, but the reason why i need this script , is because i created a scheduled task in windows so that each day at a specific hour it automatically creates a dump of my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For anyone in the same situation, here is what i did and it worked:**

I **replaced** the line:

```
set mysql_path="......\bin"
```

By:

```
set mysql_path="......\bin\mysqldump"
```

And the line:

```
%mysql_path%\mysqldump.exe --user %mysql_username% --password=%mysql_password% 
--all-databases --opt > "%output_path%\%date%_%time%.sql"
```

By:

```
%mysql_path% -u %mysql_username% -p%mysql_password% %dbname% >
%output_path%\%date_time%.sql
```

And now it is working. 
I do not really know why it didn't work using the previous method, **if you know why feel free to comment so we can all understand.**